# ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(oo)[SS -> e]: on Production, not happening on localhost

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I'm having an angular issue and I can't seem to figure out why.

When I do `ng serve` and run the code locally, everything works fine. There are no error messages or warnings.

However, when I build using `ng build --prod` and I upload the `dist` file to AWS, I now get an error on button press.

The error is:

```
    main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(oo)[SS -> e]: 
    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SS -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
    at Oe.get (https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:483678)
    at https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:494184
    at e (https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:494566)
    at Nt.get (https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:494717)
    at https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:494184
    at e (https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:494566)
    at Nt.get (https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:494717)
    at Di (https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:515973)
    at Ui.get (https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:524593)
    at hs (https://dashboard.myurl.com/main-es2015.9568554f8026ce400f37.js:1:528442)
```

It's happening on the click of a button. I'm using Angular material's `MatBottomSheet`, the function is:

```
  openEmojiSelect(): void {
    this.req.trackEvent("Editor page", "Opened emoji selector", "click")
    const bottomRef = this._bottomSheet.open(EmojiComponent, {
      panelClass: 'emoji-panel-width'
    });
    bottomRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
      console.log(this.req.getModuleEmoji())
      this.moduleData.module.image_position = this.req.getModuleEmoji();
    });
  }
```

I should be importing everything correctly:

```
//imports
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { SnippetsComponent } from './snippets/snippets.component';
import { QuestionsComponent } from './questions/questions.component';
import { EmojiComponent } from './emoji/emoji.component';
import {MatBottomSheet, MatBottomSheetRef} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { RequestsService } from '../../../requests.service';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

 //constructor
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
    public req: RequestsService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet) { }
```

I really have no idea what the problem is since it's not happening locally and I find it very difficult to debug when the error is not clear at all.

Any ideas? Thank you

Update:

I ran `ng serve --prod` which gave me a more verbatim error message:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ctrl_ngx_emoji_mart_CategoryComponent -> EmojiFrequentlyService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ctrl_ngx_emoji_mart_CategoryComponent -> EmojiFrequentlyService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for EmojiFrequentlyService!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in `angular/core`. It was already fixed in v4.4.3.

Could you please check your `angular/core` version?

Comment: My angular core seems to be version ~8.2.14

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this happens when dynamically creating a component inside MatBottomSheet, since when create a prod build, Angular minifies all the component names and when we try to find this component by name we get an error, while when working locally without compression, everything works.

I has met with such a problem, its solution is that we generate the component using its selector, it is not minified after prod build. 
Example:

```
const factory = Array.from<any>(this.resolver['_factories'].values()).find(
    (item) => item.selector === 'app-modal-container'
);
const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<ModalContainerComponent>(factory);
```

But, if this is a component from the library, then solving the problem will not be so simple.

One solution would be to try to implement such logic yourself using the same dynamic creation.
It also seems that this problem has already been encountered earlier and one of the solutions was a rollback to the previous versiono of library:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11844

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added an update to my post.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This error might be because you have incompatible version of emoji picker and Angular. You have to get the right version of emoji picker that works with your version of Angular.

Since you have mentioned you used angular v8. The last version that works with angular v8 is 1.0.6. [dependencies here](https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-emoji-mart#dependencies)